# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for dropdownlist in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have no idea why this is happening, I have set the values and debugged it, but it is just not passing the information from the controller to the view.  Here is what is going on

Model:

```
public class QueueFilterModel
{
    public string SelectedFilter { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }
    public List<string> MyFilterList { get; set; } 


}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Queue()
    {
        QueueFilterModel model = new QueueFilterModel()
        {
            SelectedFilter = "All",
            query = "SELECT * FROM [CHAVI].[dbo].[TicketQueue]",
            MyFilterList = new List<string>()

        };
        model.MyFilterList.Add("All");
        model.MyFilterList.Add("Open");
        model.MyFilterList.Add("Closed");


        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
@model RazorARPP.Models.QueueFilterModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Queue";
}

<h2>Queue</h2>


    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyForm">

        Filter
        <div>
            Filter Options:
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.DropDownList("test", new SelectList(Model.MyFilterList,Model.SelectedFilter))
        </div>


            <h3>Insert Instructions Here</h3>
                @{
                    var DB = Database.Open("CHAVI");
                    var grid = new WebGrid(DB.Query("SELECT * FROM [TicketQueue]"), null, null, 20);

                    @grid.GetHtml(
                        tableStyle: "webgrid",
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                        grid.Column(header: "Link", style: "labelcolumn", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Edit Item", "EditQueue", new { id = item.QueueID})),
                        grid.Column("Description", "Description"),
                        grid.Column("QueueDate", "QueueDate"),
                        grid.Column("Note", "Note"),
                        grid.Column("Status", "Status"),
                        grid.Column("LastUpdated", "LastUpdated")
                            )
                    )
                 }
    </form>
```

The grid part is working fine (and the query).  The problem is in the dropdown, it isn't set to anything there.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Jason's answer is spot on but I would also like to point out that if you have a SQL statement in your view, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not passing the model to view?

Should it not be

```
public ActionResult Queue()
    {
        QueueFilterModel model = new QueueFilterModel()
        {
            SelectedFilter = "All",
            query = "SELECT * FROM [CHAVI].[dbo].[TicketQueue]",
            MyFilterList = new List<string>()

        };
        model.MyFilterList.Add("All");
        model.MyFilterList.Add("Open");
        model.MyFilterList.Add("Closed");


        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:-

```
public ActionResult Queue()
{
    QueueFilterModel model = new QueueFilterModel()
    {
        SelectedFilter = "All",
        query = "SELECT * FROM [CHAVI].[dbo].[TicketQueue]",
        MyFilterList = new List<string>()

    };
    model.MyFilterList.Add("All");
    model.MyFilterList.Add("Open");
    model.MyFilterList.Add("Closed");


    return View(model);
}
```